# Ion-item content layout

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to have inside ion-item two ion-labels on the left and right side and ion-toggle in between of them.

[image: label-toggle-label-layout]

Here is html:

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col>
   <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Income</ion-label>
        <ion-toggle name="isIncome" [(ngModel)]="isIncome"></ion-toggle>
        <ion-label >Outcome</ion-label>              
    </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
   </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

I tried to put some custom styles(float,position...) to ion-label elements but it didn't worked. Is there any way to achieve this? It doesn't need to be ion-label, may be I should use some other container?

Thanks.

Comment: your </ion-row>, </ion-col> and </ion-row> are not in the right position. Can you fix it first?

Comment: Oh, yeah. Sorry. Just copy/paste mistake. (It is not like this in code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like ion-item will look for ion-label and wrap the two labels in a div. 
We can kind of hack it this way, and override the margin 0:

html

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>
      <ion-label float-left>Income</ion-label>
      <ion-label float-right>Outcome</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle name="isIncome" [(ngModel)]="isIncome" class="ion-toggle-class"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
```

css

```
.ion-toggle-class {
  margin: auto !important;
}
```

It looks good on mobile, but if you want the two labels stay closer to the toggle on web, you may want to use ion-row like RezaRahmati's answer[image]

Comment: Didn't worked. I updated my question, because I have ion-item inside ion-list, may be that affect result somehow. Because the container div is empty, so it does not take those ion-label's and ion-toggle inside. And no errors in console.

Comment: after using your updated code, it still works fine for me. The toggle is in between. What is your ionic 2 version?

Comment: I used 3.4.0 version and now I updated to 3.5.0 and your code started to work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-row>
       <ion-col text-left>
           <ion-label>Income</ion-label>
       </ion-col>
       <ion-col text-center>
           <ion-toggle name="isIncome" [(ngModel)]="isIncome"></ion-toggle>
       </ion-col>
       <ion-col text-right>
           <ion-label >Outcome</ion-label>              
       </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: That one didn't worked also. I updated my question, because I have ion-item inside ion-list, may be that affect result somehow. Because the container div is empty, so it does not take those ion-label's and ion-toggle inside. And no errors in console.